Failure to launch NiFi - ExpressionLanguageScope does not have member field VARIABLE_REGISTRY
NiFi Standard 2.0.0-M2
Attmpted to build https://github.com/linksmart/nifi-opc-ua-bundles but get the following error when starting Nifi after moving the nar to the lib folder. This worked in 1.x versions of Nifi. How do I go about building this bundle for 2.x?
Thanks!
    org.apache.nifi.text.FreeFormTextRecordSetWriter
            org.apache.nifi:nifi-record-serialization-services-nar:2.0.0-M2 || ./work/nar/extensions/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar-2.0.0-M2.nar-unpacked
    org.apache.nifi.confluent.schemaregistry.ConfluentEncodedSchemaReferenceReader
            org.apache.nifi:nifi-confluent-platform-nar:2.0.0-M2 || ./work/nar/extensions/nifi-confluent-platform-nar-2.0.0-M2.nar-unpacked
    org.apache.nifi.services.azure.storage.ADLSCredentialsControllerServiceLookup
            org.apache.nifi:nifi-azure-nar:2.0.0-M2 || ./work/nar/extensions/nifi-azure-nar-2.0.0-M2.nar-unpacked
    org.apache.nifi.box.controllerservices.JsonConfigBasedBoxClientService
            org.apache.nifi:nifi-box-services-nar:2.0.0-M2 || ./work/nar/extensions/nifi-box-services-nar-2.0.0-M2.nar-unpacked
    === End ControllerService types ===

2024-05-04 06:30:48,008 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to launch NiFi
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Class org.apache.nifi.expression.ExpressionLanguageScope does not have member field 'org.apache.nifi.expression.ExpressionLanguageScope VARIABLE_REGISTRY'
at de.fraunhofer.fit.processors.opcua.SubscribeOPCNodes.(SubscribeOPCNodes.java:70)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
at org.apache.nifi.nar.StandardExtensionDiscoveringManager.getClass(StandardExtensionDiscoveringManager.java:450)
at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.documentConfigurableComponent(DocGenerator.java:103)
at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.generate(DocGenerator.java:64)
at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:745)
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:172)
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.(NiFi.java:83)
at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:332)
2024-05-04 06:30:48,014 INFO [Thread-0] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Application Server shutdown started
pache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 21.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/local/jdk-21
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.146.1-microsoft-standard-wsl2", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
